# Evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (\sum_{k=1}^{n} (\int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}}(\sin(x))^{k}dx))$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation

I have to evaluate the following limit of a sum:
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  (\sum_{k=1}^{n} (\int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}}(\sin(x))^{k}dx))$. I ended in $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  (\int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}}(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(\sin(x))^{n}-sin)}{\sin(x)-1})dx$. From here on however I am unsure if I can introduce the limit under the integral or how to continue.

Comment: But then, as I read the main answerof the duplicate, the limit is $+\infty$, and that differs from the answer you gave.

Comment: See Jack D'Aurizio's answer.